# R programming encoding jebrish ׳‘׳“׳™׳§׳•׳× to Hebrew

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, hebrew

I have some Hebrew string along my code.
For some reason all the **Hebrew is shown in the following format ׳§׳‘׳•׳¦׳×**.

I have this line at the top of every file

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hebrew")
```

This is the output of the commend  Sys.getlocale("LC_ALL")

```
"LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255"
```

Example:

```
  hebrew <- c(
"סוג תנועה",
"מס עוסק נגדי",
"תאריך אסמכתא",
"קבוצת אסמכתא",
"מס אסמכתא",
"סכום מעמ",
"סימן",
"סכום לפני מעמ",
" עתידי",
"הערה",
"בדיקות",
"סכום.מעמ",
"סכום.לפני.מעמ",
"הערות"
 )
  print(hebrew)
```

Result:

```
׳¡׳•׳’ ׳×׳ ׳•׳¢׳”" "[1] "\u009e׳¡ ׳¢׳•׳¡׳§ ׳ ׳’׳“׳™" "׳×׳\u0090׳¨׳™׳\u009a 
׳\u0090׳¡׳\u009e׳›׳×׳\u0090" "׳§׳‘׳•׳¦׳× ׳\u0090׳¡׳\u009e׳›׳×׳\u0090" "׳\u009e׳¡ 
׳\u0090׳¡׳\u009e׳›׳×׳\u0090" "׳¡׳›׳•׳\u009d ׳\u009e׳¢׳\u009e"
[7] "׳¡׳™׳\u009e׳\u009f"       "׳¡׳›׳•׳\u009d ׳\u009c׳₪׳ ׳™ ׳\u009e׳¢׳\u009e" " 
 ׳¢׳×׳™׳“׳™"              "׳”׳¢׳¨׳”"           "׳‘׳“׳™׳§׳•׳×         "׳¡׳›׳•׳\u009
```

Comment: Can you please provide the UTF-8 codes of characters you would like to display correctly?

Comment: code: ISO/IEC 8859-8 
From wiki-  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8

Comment: My locale is German. If I put in `"\U05D8"` or `"ט"`, R prints what to my untrained eye looks like a correct letter Tet. There is something missing in your problem description.

Comment: don't know what am I missing.. 
I'm reading data from txt file, manipulate it and write xlsx/csv file
all the column name should be in Hebrew. But shown as I mention

Comment: Well, that is the missing information. Please provide a minimal reproducible example that shows how you do all of that. You should also find where exactly this issue occurs by checking intermediate results.

Comment: When print is manually  called so I do see the Hebrew letters, but when running it from the function its turn to this jebrish. Added example

Comment: "running it from the function" Which function? Your example doesnot produce the output your are showing on my machine.

Comment: I'm working on existed  project, "The function" is 800 lines of code. 
The add example show the first time that Hebrew inclouds in the function

Comment: Well, how do you expect help if you can't provide relevant details? I can think of several possible reasons for the issue but you need to narrow it down. If that means debugging 800 lines of code, I don't consider that a significant burden. I suspect an encoding or font issue when you write to the Excel file. But I don't even know which function you use for that.

Comment: manage to work it out, just move the entire function to the main file.

Comment: Really appreciate the willing to help, thank you Roland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function to the main file